# Передать объект, возвращаемый методом класса В, в конструктор класса А

Tags: java, spring

Имеется класс SeleniumWebDrivers:

```
public class SeleniumWebDrivers {

    public WebDriver getFirefox() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    }

    public WebDriver getChrome(String pathToBrowser) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToBrowser);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    }
}
```

Значения возвращаемые любым из этих методов, необходимо передать в качестве параметра при создании объекта класса Parser_v2:

```
public class Parser_v2 implements Parser {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public Parser_v2(WebDriver driver) {
        driver = this.driver;
        // initDriver();
    }

    // Other code ......
}
```

---

Пробовал делать так:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="seleniumDrivers" class="com.api.SeleniumWebDrivers" scope="prototype" />
        <bean id="parser" class="com.api.impl.parser.Parser_v2" scope="singleton">
            <constructor-arg ref="#{seleniumDrivers.getFirefox()}" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="config" class="com.api.PropertiesValues" scope="singleton"/>
    </beans>
```

Результат:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parser' defined in URL [file:src/main/resources/ApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '#{seleniumDrivers.getFirefox()}' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (9ff62278-2ed7-4fed-9c11-6c2d0300254c)' is defined
```

---

Также пробовал вот-так:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="seleniumDrivers" class="com.SeleniumWebDrivers" scope="prototype" />
        <bean id="factoryDriver" factory-bean="seleniumDrivers" factory-method="getFirefox" />
        <bean id="parser" class="com.impl.parser.Parser_v2" scope="singleton">
            <constructor-arg ref="factoryDriver"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="config" class="com.PropertiesValues" scope="singleton"/>
    </beans>
```

Получил:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parser' defined in URL [file:src/main/resources/ApplicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.api.impl.parser.Parser_v2]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

---

Метод 'getFirefox()' вызывается в обоих случаях (т. к. запускается браузер), после чего вылезают исключения. 
В первой попытке я не понимаю зачем спринг требует бин с именем 'FirefoxDriver', а во втором случае не знаю почему вместо ссылки на объект передается null.

Вопрос: как создать бин класса Parser_v2 (передав ему в конструктор параметр возвращаемый одним из методов класса SeleniumWebDrivers) ?

Comment: Пора бы уже забыть о этих xml. Почему не используете JavaConfig?

Comment: Этот проект уже давно написан без использования спринга, использую его как учебный (для изучения спринга). Сначала хотел разобраться в спринге с xml и сразу после этого переписать его используя JavaConfig...

Comment: `driver = this.driver;` - вот эта строчка в конструкторе `Parser_v2` не опечатка?

Comment: @zRrr, да, конечно, это опечатка. Спасибо за помощь! Можете написать ответ, я отмечу его как лучший.